# Converting a list ([a]) to a type-level length-indexed list

Tags: haskell

I'm fairly inexperienced with Haskell, but essentially I've started working with DataKinds and GADTs. I have a GADT which represents a list that "knows" its length:

```
data NSL :: N -> * -> * where
Null :: NSL 'Zero a
More :: a -> NSL n a -> NSL ('Incr n) a
```

which is created from the natural data representation

```
data N :: * where
    Zero :: N
    Incr :: N -> N
```

So my question is, how do I create a function

```
fromList :: [a] -> NSL n a
```

I've tried working with Foldable and similar ideas, but I can't quite wrap my head around it.

Comment: I don't think you can have a function of that type. You can make a function where the `n` part of the type is "hidden" in a existential type, but I'm not sure if that maintains the usefulness of this. I have written something along those lines [here](https://github.com/roboguy13/natural-constructions/blob/master/examples/vect/Vect.hs) using [this](https://github.com/roboguy13/natural-constructions/blob/master/src/Data/Natural.hs). That hasn't been cleaned up to be as readable it probably could be yet, hah.

Comment: With that type, `fromList [] :: NSL ('Incr 'Zero) Void` would type check. The only possible way to implement this is using infinite recursion. You want an existential, not universal, quantification on `n`.

Comment: I've marked this question as a duplicate because, although the lead-up to the question is different (you are not using singletons`), the answer is still spot on.